# jini starter kit 2.1 for installing blitz javaSpaces

Tags: java, jini, javaspaces

I need to set up blitz JavaSpaces [(here)](http://www.dancres.org/bjspj/docs/docs/install_guide.html). On Blitz installation guide one of the requiered packages is [the starter kit for JINI 2.1](http://www.dancres.org/bjspj/docs/docs/required_packages.html), but the link offered is broken and I can't seem to find it anywhere else. I've been looking at Apache River Project, ¿should I install this instead of the missing JINI 2.1? There's really little or no documentation at all and it really bugs me that blitz is mantaining a broken link to one of its prerequisites. That gave me the idea for this other question ¿is the blitz implementation reliable?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm supporting a legacy application and needed this as well. You can find the starterkit here: [maven repository](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jini/jini-starterkit/2.1/jini-starterkit-2.1.zip).